# Symfony and jQuery.data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony1

I have an ajax navigation system in my app. Each ajax link is of class `ajax` and the page it needs to load is saved in an `aurl` attribute, for example:

```
<a class="ajax" aurl="/user/posts/3/edit">Edit Post</a>
```

The aurl is given to the element using symfony's `url_for` method in the server-side.

I thought about more elegant way of saving the element's aurl attribute, like `jQuery.data()`, but how can i use it from the server side? creating a script after each element to set it's `aurl` doesn't seem like a good solution..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a class="ajax" data-aurl="/user/posts/3/edit">Edit Post</a>
```

Then you can access it through `.data('aurl')` if you use a recent jQuery version (1.5 or newer AFAIK).

However, why don't you simply set the `href` (which should be set anyway) and then use `$(this).attr('href')` to get the url and use `e.preventDefault();` (with `e` being the first argument of the click handler function) to prevent the link from loading without AJAX?

Comment: I wanted to use data so that i don't have to spread the links all over the app.. so I would have `<a class="ajax edit">Edit Post</a>` and it's url will be saved "behind the scenes"

Comment: If you want to set data related to the element it should be set there, i.e. through a `data-` attribute. Moving URLs away from the related links would just make things confusing.